# How to truncate and keep the last word in excel formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a an excel formula that truncates the value in a cell to a certain characters i.e 30 characters and keeps the last word even if it crosses the 30 character limit.
The problem is if it is stopping at 30 characters in the middle of the word then it gives an error, as my formula is trying to find space after 30 characters which there won't be if there is no word after that, this formula works only if it has space after 30 characters

```
=IF(LEN(A2)>60,LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,60)-1),A2)
```

What I want is the sentence truncated upto 30 characters and keep the last word if the 30 characters stops in the middle of the word then it should keep the word.

Comment: There is no VBA in this question. And the text says 30 while the formula says 60. Hint: ISERROR is your friend: `=IF (LEN(A2) <= 60, A2, IF (ISERROR(FIND(" ", A2)), ---No spaces---, ---Has spaces---))`.

Comment: You say 30 but your formula says 60

Comment: `FIND(" ",A2&" ",60)`

Comment: lol.. i was testing around and pasted the 60 formula..my mistake.. thanks for the point out and for the answer scott and AlexP